# How to fetch all products from one magento website and insert them into other using SOAP call?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, catalog, soap

I want to fetch all products from one magento website (CE 1.7) to insert them into other magento installation (EE 1.12), using SOAP api call (I know that'll be really slooooow). I'll break it into chunks as I only have access to api username and key.

What are all the information I have to fetch and insert?

I've gone through [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) and got confused on which methods I should use and which are all the methods I can skip.

Can anyone streamline the ideas and give me a solution?

> note:
>
> categories have already been manually replicated.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the possibility to make an export from the source-side, you might want to consider using Daniel Sloofs Apiimport on the target-side: https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport

It consumes the standard Magento ImportExport CSV format through SOAP, re-assembles it and pipes it to the Core ImportExport implementation. Some clever re-indexing included.

Comment: that's a nice module, but the problem is the export file from source site

Comment: how could I test this module in localhost? I've never installed a modman/modman module?